Horror movie with the ghost having weakness towards light
I remember watching a movie on Star Movies, 6-7 yrs ago. It was about a  family impaired by a ghost who come only through darkness. It wasn't able to appear in light. It weared a teared long coat. Starting a woman has been killed by this ghost and her son save his life by getting in bathroom, bath tub covered full of light. In last portions they try to escape from building by jumping stair landing to landing because the landing have only lights.
Finally they reach in a lighthouse and kill that ghost by the light house light. I don't remember its name.

Sounds like Darkness Falls (2003)

A vengeful spirit has taken the form of the Tooth Fairy to exact vengeance on the town that lynched her 150 years earlier. Her only opposition is the only child, now grown up, who has survived her before.




